# Finding MAX of SUM of sales while incorporating field from separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, max

I really need some help regarding max and sum for two tables. So there are two tables.

**Supplies**

```
+-------------+------+----------+
|supplier_id  | city | supplier |
+-------------+------+----------+
```

**Orders**

```
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+------+
| order_id | supplier_id | order_date | sale_amt | city | 
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+------+
```

I need to find the **top supplier (maximum combined sales amount) in each city** in this format:

```
+------+----------+----------+
| city | supplier | sale_amt |
+------+----------+----------+
```

### The ISSUE

I can find the sum of the sales amount along with city and supplier name(supplier) fine.
But cannot derive the MAXIMUM of those sales because using (group by) for BOTH city and supplier gives me multiple suppliers per city where I need only the TOP supplier for EACH city.
If just city name was needed it wouldn't be an issue, but needing the supplier name causes this problem.

This is the query I'm using right now and what I have so far.

```
SELECT s.city, s.supplier, SUM(sale_amt)
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Supplies s
ON o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
GROUP BY s.city, s.supplier
ORDER BY s.city
```

Your help and guidance would be much appreciated.

EDIT: After trying all your solutions and hitting snags here or there, came up with my own messy code below. This definitely has holes and could be written much better.

```
SELECT A.city, B.supplier, A.max_sale_amt
FROM
    (
    SELECT city, MAX(tot) as max_sale_amt
    FROM (
        SELECT supplier_id, SUM(sale_amt) as tot
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY supplier_id ) as D
        LEFT JOIN Supplies s
        ON D.supplier_id = Supplies.id
        GROUP BY city
    ) A,

    (
    SELECT s.city, s.supplier, SUM(sale_amt) as sum_amt
    FROM Orders o, Supplies s
        WHERE o.supplier_id = s.id
    GROUP BY s.supplier, s.city
    ) B
WHERE A.city= B.city AND A.max_sale_amt= B.sum_amt
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES s.city, s.supplier, SUM(sale_amt)
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Supplies s ON o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
GROUP BY s.city, s.supplier
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.city ORDER BY SUM(sale_amt) DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `DENSE_RANK` as follows:

```
select city, supplier, sm_sales_amount from
(SELECT s.city, s.supplier, SUM(sale_amt) as sm_sales_amount,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY s.city ORDER BY SUM(sale_amt) DESC) as rn
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Supplies s ON o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
GROUP BY s.city, s.supplier) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: This will have a higher computational cost than other solutions I think? the ranking and the left join?

Comment: It will have the same cost as compared to other solution.

Comment: @Neve It will actually have a lower cost than  Tim Biegeleisen's solution because ordering remains the same (assuming you already have an index `(s.city, s.supplier_id)`)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works

```
SELECT s.city
  ,s.supplier
  ,max(sale_amt)
FROM Orders   o
  ,Supplies s
WHERE o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id(+)
GROUP BY s.city
     ,s.supplier
ORDER BY s.city
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this because I am too lazy to make the tables but I'd be using a temp table for an interim step either using a desc sort and then select top records, or using a max selection from the temp. Approximately something like this

```
SELECT      city, supplierid, SUM(sale_amt)
INTO        #SumSupPerCity
FROM        Orders o
GROUP BY    city, supplierid 
ORDER BY    SUM(sale_amt) DESC;

SELECT      Top 1 * 
FROM        #MaxSumSupPerCity;
```

Comment: The group by partitioning option will work for you too I think